# Wire in breaker panel is dead

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

The left side of my kitchen stopped working recently. I replaced the breaker with no avail. I then took off the breaker and tested the black wire itself. It reads 0v how do I replace this wire?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If wire is removed from breaker, it must read 0v or you have bigger problem.  More likely problem in or near kitchen outlets/lights.  Was old breaker tripped?

Comment: No it was not tripped

Comment: Do you have any GFCI outlets that need to be reset? Outlets with the 'test/reset" buttons?

Comment: Does your 240Volt appliances still work... stove, oven, water heater, etc. if electric?

Comment: The gfcis that I have don’t reset due to having no power and my 240v things work, but they are on a different breaker

Comment: Would start with outlets/switches and see if any wire undone/broken/burned.  Start with closes to breaker.  Breaker off/removed.

Comment: Ok let’s back up. Where did you test the wire at the circuit breaker or at the dead receptacle? Don’t panic failed wiring is not uncommon when a circuit has been overloaded. There is probably another device between this receptacle and the panel. A GFCI device between or a junction box a broken wire is not uncommon we need to find where there is voltage. There could be receptacles on the other side of the wall. Time to figure out what is dead.

Comment: I tested the wire at every receptacle, switch, and the breaker. They are all dead. Pictured above are my breaker and the first junction box that is on the circuit

Comment: Can you get a piece of wire long enough to go from first outlet back to close to breaker?  Remove black from breaker and attach new wire to black wire at outlet.  See if any resistance between the two,  repeat with white wire.

Comment: Did you test the output end of the breaker with the breaker on? This is the end where the (black) wire attaches. One probe on one breaker screw  and the other probe on a ground or neutral bar.

Comment: @JimStewart yea I did that

Comment: And what did you get? Of course I assume the breaker was in place, snapped in.

Comment: I got 122 volts

Comment: And yes it was in place snapped in

Answer (score 1):

Now we know the power is good at the breaker.
Trace the black wire back to where it comes in the panel.
Follow the white wire that the black comes in with to the grounded buss make sure the wire is not broken and is connected to the buss.

Next go to the first receptacle pull it out. Check for voltage, that wire splice looks small to me like 14 awg if back stabs were used the failure is at the last working receptacle or first non working (once the splice is put together).

If that is the first receptacle between the panel and that receptacle the wire is broken and needs to be replaced.

Remember to check the other side of the wall I have been called many times to fix circuits where the problem was a GFCI in another room almost exactly opposite from the dead receptacle.